# angular material card toolbar

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

i would like to create a toolbar for angular md-cards.

something similar to this image
[image]

```
<md-card layout="column" >
              <md-toolbar>
                <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                  <h3>Card Header</h3>
                  <span flex></span>
                  <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                    <md-icon md-font-icon="fa-calendar" class="fa" aria-label="open menu"></md-icon>
                  </md-button>
                  <md-button class="md-icon-button">
                    <md-icon md-font-icon="fa-user" class="fa" aria-label="open menu"></md-icon>
                  </md-button>
                </div>
              </md-toolbar>
              </md-card-content>Card Content</md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

is there any current directives for ngMaterial -angular material- that can
be used to get such nice toolbar for cards or do i have to make custom css for it ?

Comment: Your template is almost complete, what else do you need? Round the corners, adjust the color, add a bottom border and you are done. There is nothing pre made.

Comment: I don't get it....you have shown code to do it with no explanation of problem. Note double close tags `</md-card-content>`

Comment: @charlietfl my problem is following code will produce toolbar with primary color Bg -blue background not white-, and font, text size and color all not optimized for card toolbar.

Comment: can you please put this in a fiddle, plunk etc.?

Comment: can use multiple themes if that helps. As for style would have to customize to taste

Comment: As I have that, there is nothing out-of-the-box. You can add a theme or 5 lines of CSS to do what u want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Material toolbar is using your theme primary color as the toolbar's background-color by default.

toolbar-theme.scss implementation:
https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/toolbar/toolbar-theme.scss

One way to use the background-colors you like is to override the css with !important

```
md-toolbar {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

Another way is to set your accent color as white, you can follow this on how to configure theme colors in your app:
https://material.angularjs.org/0.11.4/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme

Then, you can use md-accent in your toolbar directive, for example:

```
<md-toolbar class="md-accent">
  <h2>title</h2>
</md-toolbar>
```

But this method is under the assumption your accent theme color is white. If you are following Google material design, then you should set multiple themes as charlietfl said.

If you want the font, text size, and color like the picture you showed, you can inspect elements on your browser to get the styles it is using and put it to your CSS.